# Catastophic backtracking issue with HTML

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to scrape a series of webpages using PHP, grabbing all of the content between the  tag and the earliest  tag.  This is the regex that I'm using:

```
|(?<=div id="body">).*?</div>|s
```

This seems to be working perfectly fine for most of the pages I'm looking at.  However, it's not returning anything for a few others.  I plugged the regex into the regex101.com tester, and it told me that the problem was with catastrophic backtracking.  I tried removing the lookbehind language, and even playing around with things like:

```
|id="body">.*?</div>|s
```

However, the problem is still persisting.  I've looked at some other questions about catastrophic backtracking, as well as the http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html article, but I can't figure out how to apply their fixes to this particular case.

Comment: I don't see that falling into catastrophic backtracking. Can you link us to the regex101 example you tried?

Comment: Sure.  https://regex101.com/r/kY8qK0/1

Comment: Why do you need a lookbehind? `div id="body">.*?</div>` works just as well.

Comment: Since that is a fixed width lookbehind and the end is a literal, the  `.*?` should not cause backtrack problems.

Comment: Even without the lookbehind (i.e., using your version), the regex throws a catastrophic backtracking error.

Comment: I think its the length of the match text. It matches `len 105695` when I run it from [regexformat7 app](http://www.regexformat.com)

Comment: This isn't catastrophic backtracking. It's only a timeout. It takes too long to process a match from char 3,962 to char 108,334. I guess regex101 assumes it's due to a catastrophic backtracking (logically, they didn't expect a user entering a *catastrophically* long text :-) ... That said, don't use regex to parse HTML

Comment: Ah; thanks!  If not regex, then, how should I parse HTML?

Comment: It's a catastrophically long match.

Comment: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/5290909)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are known to cause catastrophic backtracking with large HTML contents. In this case, the problem is surely with the look-behind and lazy dot matching, when each time the regex engine advances one symbol to the right, it must check if the symbol is preceded with the specified substring, and if it reached enough characters to yield a match.

A good idea of how this regex works is looking at the regex101 [*regex debugger*](https://regex101.com/r/kY8qK0/1) section.

As to how to parse your HTML, PHP DOMDocument and DOMXPath are your best friends:

```
$html = "<<YOUR_HTML_STRING_HERE>>";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
// Above is the DOM initialization from string example, below is parsing
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@id="body"]'); // Get all DIV tags with id=body

foreach($divs as $div) { 
  echo $dom->saveHTML($div); // Echo the HTML, can be added to array
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/R8REWX)

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @stribizhev Are you positive this is *catastrophic backtracking*, as the problem isn't really with exponential backtracking steps as it would occur with nested quantifiers? -Notice it raises the same error without the lookbehind, which I believe it's a plain old *O(n)* timeout.

Comment: @Mariano: I use the term catastrophic backtracking widely. Timeout is caused by a huge amount of backtracking steps.

Comment: I see. And I don't know if there's a formal definition either. I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: I wouldn't say it's catastrophic backtracking. For an average HTML document, this is at most a linear operation. However, in a long HTML document, the backtracking on `.*?` to advance to the next character exhausts the backtracking limit, leading to the match being interrupted.